# What would the purgatorial lake be like?

Tags: water, water-bodies, rivers

The purgatorial lake in an artificial lake formed from the five rivers of heaven and hell. These rivers are:

- The syrup river of heaven, a river of golden syrup
- The seed river of heaven, a river of human semen
- The slime river of hell, a river of the liquid from rotting carcasses
- The blood river of hell, a river of human blood
- The flaming river of heaven and hell, a river of burning kerosene

Each of the five rivers contributes the same amount of liquid to the lake, and the lake is fully mixed through. What would the liquid in the lake be like?

Comment: dry, with crystalized and burned syrup, the rest is vapour.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for there is "corpse liquor".

Comment: Delicious. That's what it would be. Especially the rotting corpses part

Comment: A lot of people are saying "sludge" but if my math is right, there's far more than enough energy when burned in one liter of kerosene (from the kerosene river) to evaporate 4 liters (from the other 4 rivers) of water, which is quite a bit since evaporating water is extremely energy intensive.  If the kerosene is used in the right way, wonderland's comment could be correct and the result could be a humid flatland of carbonized gunk at a temperature hot enough to fry an egg.  Probably would smell awful but not as bad as the sludge answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Sludge:

I'm afraid it wouldn't be a lake. It would rapidly fill with a huge clotted mass of rotting organic matter, selecting for microorganisms with a tolerance for the relatively high concentration of hydrocarbons  (although much of the kerosene would volatilize off, with many fires and explosions from this and methane). So a rancid cesspool. I'm not sure of the densities of the clotted organics relative to kerosene, so I can't say if you'd have burnt floating islands of clots or not. Possibly some thrusting
up though the kerosene layer.

The material wouldn't STAY mixed for long. Paraffin would likely form a coating over the top of the lake because these fluids are immiscible. Any ignition source would lead to flaming pools of floating kerosene. Depending on how quickly it evaporated or burned, the lake underneath might be either aerobic or anaerobic, also affecting the mix of organisms feeding on the organics. Between the fires and decay, it would be quite toasty.

Given enough time, I'm sure things would evolve that fed off this mess, and the nature of what could live in it would radically alter it's ecosystem. An anaerobic environment would be REALLY foul and mostly microbial. Outside organisms might dive into the mess to feed OR some bizarre stork-like animal might dip under the paraffin to draw up organics.  An aerobic environment would support a broader array of organisms feeding off the organics directly, but the aerobic environment would mean more fires and volatiles, so organisms would need to deal with fires and cooked organics turning to boiled messes. I suspect the breakdown of all that stuff would rapidly deplete the oxygen in the water, so it would most likely be a huge anaerobic fermenter.

Answer (score 0):

I think there'd be a large fraction of the resulting lake which would gelatinize. Between the mucilaginous component of the semen, the hydrolyzed collagen from the corpses, and the heat provided by the burning kerosene, I think the top layer would be an extremely objectionable gel reminiscent of black pudding. There might also be a layer of [adipocere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipocere) floating on top.